# PDFKit open last read page in a PDF file

Tags: ios, swift, swift5, pdfkit

So I am using PDFKit to display a PDF and and save/open the last read page.
Here's my code.
Problem is, the last open page is always 2-4 pages ahead of the one that's actually saved in user defaults. I am not sure what's wrong here.

Ignore the the code with the WebView for iOS versions below 11.

```
func readBook() {

    if let oldBookView = self.view.viewWithTag(3) {
        oldBookView.removeFromSuperview()
        // This removes the old book view when the user chooses a new book language
    }

    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        let pdfView: PDFView = PDFView()
        let path = BookManager.getBookPath(bookLanguageCode: book.bookLanguageCode)
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
        if let pdfDocument = PDFDocument(url: url) {
            pdfView.displayMode = .singlePageContinuous
            pdfView.autoScales = true
            pdfView.document = pdfDocument
            pdfView.tag = 3 // I assigned a tag to this view so that later on I can easily find and remove it when the user chooses a new book language
            let lastReadPage = getLastReadPage()

            if let page = pdfDocument.page(at: lastReadPage) {
                pdfView.go(to: page)
                // Subscribe to notifications so the last read page can be saved
                // Must subscribe after displaying the last read page or else, the first page will be displayed instead
                NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.saveLastReadPage),name: .PDFViewPageChanged, object: nil)
            }
        }

        self.containerView.addSubview(pdfView)
        setConstraints(view: pdfView)
        addTapGesture(view: pdfView)
    } else {
        let path = BookManager.getBookPath(bookLanguageCode: book.bookLanguageCode)
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
        let webView: WKWebView = WKWebView()
        webView.loadFileURL(url, allowingReadAccessTo: url)
        webView.tag = 3 // I assigned a tag to this view so that later on I can easily find and remove it when the user chooses a new book language

        self.containerView.addSubview(webView)
        setConstraints(view: webView)
        addTapGesture(view: webView)
    }
}

private func getLastReadPage() -> Int {
    let readPagesDictionary: [String:Int] = DataManager.UserDefaultsManager.value(for: .lastReadPage)
    let bookLanguage = book.bookLanguageCode
    let lastReadPage = readPagesDictionary[bookLanguage]

    return lastReadPage!
}

@available(iOS 11.0, *)
@objc private func saveLastReadPage(notification: Notification) {
    let pdfView = notification.object as! PDFView
    var page = pdfView.currentDestination?.page?.pageRef?.pageNumber
    let bookLanguage = book.bookLanguageCode
    var readPageDict: [String:Int] = DataManager.UserDefaultsManager.value(for: .lastReadPage)
    readPageDict.updateValue(page!, forKey: bookLanguage)
    DataManager.UserDefaultsManager.set(readPageDict, for: .lastReadPage)
}
```

Comment: I suspect do the documents you are looking at have several pages of front matter (a title page, table of contents, acknowledgements etc…)  before the ACTUAL page numbered page 1?  I suspect one numbering scheme you are using is using the pages physical order in the PDF file, while the other numbering scheme is referencing the logical page number of the page in the "book" stored in the PDF.

Comment: No I am using the page number that the PDFKit sends back through the delegate. It's the same page number that I save and open the PDF file at again.

Answer (score -1):

For me, I'm seeing an "Index from 0" vs. "Index from 1" issue.
I believe that under the hood some changes have recently been made to PDFKit.

It's possible this wouldn't have worked in the past...

Using 
`Apple Swift version 5.2.4 (swiftlang-1103.0.32.9 clang-1103.0.32.53)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.5.0` and `Xcode Version 11.5 (11E608c)`

This works for me:

```
   var currentPageNumber: Int  {
        let result = pdfView.currentPage?.pageRef?.pageNumber ?? 0
        return result > 0 ? result - 1 : 0
    }
```

One Possible way to save the currently viewed page's page number:

```
    /// integer(forKey:) returns 0 when not found, which is perfect place to scroll to
    /// this only addresses the case you are viewing the same document that was saved to user defaults
    /// if you've gone to a new file, start at 0 there
    /// you could update the document proxy to contain a last page saved if you have one, 
    /// and when opening the pdf, save that to user defaults
    func saveCurrentPageNumber() {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(currentPageNumber, forKey: pageNumberKey)
    }
```

I call this from `viewWillAppear()`

```
/// Check user defaults and scroll to last page viewed (or 0 if none)
func scrollToSavedPage() {
    let pageNumber = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: pageNumberKey)
    if let goToPage = document?.page(at: pageNumber) {
        pdfView.go(to: goToPage)
    }
}
```

Again: **YMMV**, but this works for me.